# List of Primes in UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request

Are there websites/databases containing lists ordered by norm of prime/irreducible elements in domains like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]$ for easy reference, such as the one here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Gaussian_integer_factorizations

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the software library PARI might be of use to you. Have a look at http://oeis.org/A078458/a078458.txt